# Question regarding earnings by major

Tags: collegescorecard

I wasn't able to find earnings by major.  Do those data exist in the database?  If not, have you considered collecting them?

Comment: This won't tell you earnings by major for a particular institution, which is your original question, but it may be useful anyway. Here's a research report on earnings by major across institutions: https://cew.georgetown.edu/wp-content/uploads/The-Economic-Value-of-College-Majors-Full-Report-web-FINAL.pdf

Comment: do you have any update on posting earnings data by major, for each school? That would be very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Scorecard does not provide earnings by major/program of study. Earnings data are collected by matching student grant and loan data to tax records and past student grant/loan records do not have this level of detail. However, recent changes in student grant/loan reporting might allow this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The site has a data dictionary [here](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/CollegeScorecardDataDictionary-09-08-2015.csv) that you can search for what you want. It does not contain major in this version. It does contain some degree fields. Good luck.